# How can you modify the styling of a compiled macOS app without the Xcode project and without additional apps?

Tags: xcode, macos, toolbar, titlebar, info.plist

Does anybody know, how to change the appearance of the title bar and/or toolbar of a simple & small one-window cocoa macOS application without accessing the Xcode or installing third party applications? It's for a screen recording video project, I want to do.

I know, that there are possibilities within the applications info.plist (for example changing the app title inside the top macOS Menu Bar) but I would like to be able to change the apps window title itself and/or colors and/or fonts inside the window title bar or toolbar if possible.

Opening the app in another container window or via terminal or Applescript and adding custom parameters or even an overlay in the right position to change the styling would be okay if this is possible?

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

in short: Nibs
Nib File Viewer works until Xcode 10
saving, recompiling if possible
good luck